# PHP load multiple XML data without numbering

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm facing some problems trying to load multiple data from an XML file.
I want to load all XML data without having to number them [0],[1], etc. how can I accomplish that?

PHP

```
<?php
  echo"<center>";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('channels.xml') or die('Failed to read data');
  echo $xml->channels[0]->name . "<br>";
  echo "<img class='responsive' src='";
  echo $xml->channels[0]->banner;
  echo "'><br>";
  echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' type='text' name='url' value='";
  echo $xml->channels[0]->url;
  echo "'><br>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='PLAY CHANNEL'><br>";

  $xml = simplexml_load_file('channels.xml') or die('Failed to read data');
  echo $xml->channels[1]->name . "<br>";
  echo "<img class='responsive' src='";
  echo $xml->channels[1]->banner;
  echo "'><br>";
  echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' type='text' name='url' value='";
  echo $xml->channels[1]->url;
  echo "'><br>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='PLAY CHANNEL'><br>";
  echo"</center>";

if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
    shell_exec("sudo killall player.bin");
    shell_exec("sudo player `youtube-dl -g ".($_POST['url'])." `>> /dev/null &");
}
?>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <channels>
    <banner>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Sky-news-logo.svg/768px-Sky-news-logo.svg.png</banner>
    <url>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoMdktPbSTixAyNGwb-UYkQ/live</url>
  </channels>
  <channels>
    <banner>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/DqTJr6u-LpXfWyrJscDsoa_XdZsXLTm1PXDLw_eJYRAlwx0RtNO4thah_YQhKk-vWmeSHkIfSGsClFIQmTWDS0iNGM3VeeEXrSzYSVPRFyEf5NQ9TVw0B9KYXg</banner>
    <url>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg/live</url>
  </channels>
</data>
```

Comment: Have run my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [the examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), you can loop over elements with the same name with a normal `foreach` loop:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('channels.xml') or die('Failed to read data');
foreach ( $xml->channels as $channelsElement ) {
    echo $channelsElement->name;
}
```